# How come this image won't resize to fit the sprite?

Tags: apache-flex, image, actionscript, scale

I have this snippet of ActionScript code that is supposed to resize an image to fit the sprite: (as in *rescale* the image *not* just clip it)

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        [Embed(source = 'img.png')]
        private var TheImage:Class;

        public static const  TheImageWidth:Number = 1300;
        public static const TheImageHeight:Number = 1300;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point

            var image:Bitmap = new TheImage();

            addChild(image);

            image.scaleX = width / TheImageWidth;
            image.scaleY = height / TheImageHeight;
        }

    }

}
```

Why isn't it working? The image isn't getting the right dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
image.image.content.width = TheImageWidth;
image.image.content.height = TheImageHeight;
```

Comment: Nope. `image` is not a property or method of `image`.

Comment: That's what I get for not reading the question properly! I assumed that image was an Image, not a Bitmap...

Try using the transform property and assign a matrix instead of using the scaleX and Y properties.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the something like this for imagery. We had issue with using MapImage and the MapImageLayer using ArcGIS for Flex 2.5. It seems to be fix in 3.5, Anyways I had to put an image into a sprite and paint the image based on the sprites width. If you want to scale the image to the sprite's dimensions you will need to use the Matrix API and use the scale method. The values passed into this should be the sprite's width divided by the image's width assuming the image is bigger than your sprite. Do the same with the height. Here is the code I used to accomplish the task.

```
                const point:MapPoint = geometry as MapPoint;

                sprite.x = toScreenX(map, point.x);
                sprite.y = toScreenY(map, point.y);

                // grab left x point for upper left then for lower right
                // actua
                var bottomLeftX:Number = toScreenX(map, geomertyWrapper.extent.xmin);
                var topRightX:Number = toScreenX(map, geomertyWrapper.extent.xmax);

                var bottomLeftY:Number = toScreenY(map, geomertyWrapper.extent.ymin);
                var topRightY:Number = toScreenY(map, geomertyWrapper.extent.ymax);

                iconWidth = Math.abs(topRightX - bottomLeftX);
                iconHeight = Math.abs(topRightY - bottomLeftY);

                sprite.width = iconWidth;
                sprite.height = iconHeight;

                var scaleX:Number = iconWidth/bitmapData.width;
                var scaleY:Number = iconHeight/bitmapData.height;

                m_matrix.a = 1.0;
                m_matrix.d = 1.0;
                m_matrix.scale(scaleX, scaleY);
                m_matrix.tx = -iconWidth / 2;
                m_matrix.ty = -iconHeight / 2;

                //Values needed for drawing AlertNotificationInstance

                sprite.graphics.beginBitmapFill(m_bitmapData, m_matrix, false, false);
                sprite.graphics.drawRect(m_matrix.tx, m_matrix.ty, 
                    iconWidth, 
                    iconHeight);
                sprite.graphics.endFill();
```

Hope this helps.